# cannot get high resolution from ipad

Tags: ios, ipad

I am trying to set the screen resolution of a project to 2048x1536 (retina display on ipad).

I created a new single page app in Xcode using Swift, targeted ipad, set deployment target to various values (from 8 to 11), clicked Requires full screen, and chose only landscape modes.

I changed everywhere I could find in the storyboard, but no matter what I do, it is returning 1024x768. when I to an NSLog print from the ViewDidLoad function.

Can someone possibly shed some light on how to use the ipad to its best resolution?

Jerry

Comment: It is 1024 x 768 “points”, on your retina screen (which is 2048 x 1536 when you multiply that by the [`scale`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen/1617836-scale) of the screen).

Comment: So, you _are_ using it to its best resolution, but they scale the coordinate system it so that fonts aren't rendered so small that they are unreadable. Perhaps you can tell us what you're doing and we can advise you further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xcode the size of elements and the screen are measured in points. Each device has a scale factor that is applied to the points which means developers don't have to target specific screen sizes that have the same ratios.

Apple explain it a bit here: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH14-SW7

Graphical representation here too: https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions